# python fabric logging

Tags: python, logging, fabric

I came across fabric modules - Its really cool. It works well for me. Now I have an issue ,how to collect output from fabric script?

```
# cat fabfile.py
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm

env.hosts = ['localhost' , '172.16.10.112','172.16.10.106']
env.user='testuser'
env.password = 'testuser'
@parallel
def uptime():
    run('uname -a')
```

I would like to use logging modules with fabric and use them inside the code itself .- Don't want to use normal redirection like "fab uptime &> log.out "

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like `fabric` itself doesn't use `logging`.

[Issue#57](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/57) is already opened regarding that, but I'm afraid that until it's fixed you'll need to stick to redirection or have a look at some of the branches in github with changes to do that:

- [tswicegood/fabric](https://github.com/tswicegood/fabric/commit/89c3cec8a8aa10d583a35a6201c1b4fd424f795f)
- <s>[ampledata/fabric](https://github.com/ampledata/fabric/commit/cd691df3285c67cc9ab135984b9cb5c2e0f857be)</s>
- [pmuller's streamlogger gist](https://gist.github.com/pmuller/2376336)

Comment: Second link is now broken/private.

Comment: @cevaris Thanks for your comment. Yes, it looks like the repository is no longer available. I'm not removing the link, but using strikethrough formatting to make that clear.